# Vue DevTools beta not appear in Brave Browser developer tools

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools

I'm using **Vue DevTools beta version** for my **Vue 3 Application**. it's perfectly **detecting vue app** but it's **not appear in Browser developer tools**. when I using **Vue 2 application** it's **appear on Browser developer tools in perfectly**.

I need to use Vue DevTools beta version with vue 3 cli application.

How can I solve this problem?
**I'm using brave browser.**

Thankyou.

Comment: Why is the question specific to Brave? Did you confirm that it works differently in Chrome? You're limiting it to Brave users this way. The problem you describe looks odd. It should be the opposite, Vue devtools stable works with Vue 2, beta with Vue 3. Switch between them when needed. If beta doesn't work for Vue 3, make sure you don't run in production.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can i know how figure out vue app in production or development?

Comment: It's in prod when you run 'build'. Also see 'mode' in CLI docs